# Looping through an array to find my name and then print it out

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a code academy tutorial that searches text for my name and then pushes it into an array and console.logs it. I'm having an issue, the position of the letters is being logged to the console instead of the actual letters themselves. here is my code:

```
/*jshint multistr:true */

var text = "blah bleh blih bloh blah blah mike bleh tak tik mike";
var myName = "mike";
var hits = [];

for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
  if (text[i] ==="m"){
   for (j = i; j <= i + myName.length; j++){  
   hits.push(j);

   }
 }
```

}

```
if (hits.length === 0){
console.log("Your name wasn't found!");   

} else {

 console.log(hits);   
}
```

the preceding code displays [ 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52 ] which is the position of the letters in my text variable, instead of the letters themselves

Comment: Inside your loop, you're calling `hits.push(j);`. What do you think that's doing?

Comment: `hits.push(text[j]);`

Comment: it should be `text[i]=="mike"`, remove the second loop and push `text[i]`. Otherwise `text = "morning bla bla mike bla bla"` will match the `m` to `morning`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you know the position of the letters is in the variable `j`, before it's pushed on to `hits`.

You know those position refer specifically to the variable `text`.

You already refereed to a letter at a specific position in `text` with `text[i]`.

So what could you push onto hits instead of `j` to refer to the specific letter at `j`'s position in `text`?

(if you just want to answer comment below — I'm never sure with code academy questions)

Comment: hits.push(text[j]); got it, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

It's smarter to use Regular Expressions for this sort of thing.  To find instances of a substring in a string:

```
var str = 'Greetings, SomeKittens, how are you, SomeKittens?';
var nameCount = str.match(/SomeKittens/g).length;
```